# While loop not stopping despite condition value changing

Tags: java, concurrency, java-threads

I have the following lines of code in my `main()` function:

[image]

The method `Open()` returns the value of a boolean variable `open` in the barber class. The run method in the barber class sets `open` variable to true but the while loop in the main function doesn't stop. It's like it's seeing `barber.Open()` as false forever, despite the change. 
This is the relative code in the barber class :

[image]

[image]

Comment: When are you calling the run method?

Comment: @Pablo I'm calling it via the start method as TheBarber is a thread in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the `open` field as `volatile` to ensure that write in one thread is visible to a reader in the other thread:

```
private volatile boolean open;
```

Your current problem is most likely related to Happens-Before relationship in Java Memory Model. Currently you are not using any instruction that would generate the necessary memory barrier. Using `volatile`, which is just one of the ways to get it, is explained in detail [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/106787/1602555). If you prefer a more in-depth read try [Close Encounters of The Java Memory Model Kind](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/) by Shipilev.